# Selecting style data from DevTools in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I want to copy style data from DevTools with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> I have trouble selecting text.

Why?

Before releasing the mouse pointer, the text seems selected.

[image: before releasing mouse pointer]

After releasing the mouse pointer, the selection is gone and I get a blinking cursor (at the arrow):

[image: after releasing the mouse pointer]

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Consider reporting it on https://crbug.com if it wasn't reported already. See also if it's already fixed in Chrome Canary which you can install separately.

Comment: Could the actual behavior be useful for something?

Comment: Also, this behavior has really been for years so it is maybe intentional.

Comment: IIUC, I don't see how it could be useful. And there are bugs that exist for years.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=880269

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are dragging your mouse over the text in order to select it. Rather than doing that, try clicking the selector.

[image: DevTools UI after clicking]

The entire selector will be highlighted. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: So I will not be able to copy a part of the selector?

Comment: Once you're in edit mode, I think you can select just a part of the selector.